# What's the Sonos Cloud Queue GET /version periodic polling interval?

Tags: sonos

We've recently started adding programmed radio to our existing SMAPI implementation. I've followed the Sonos Developer documentation and (eventually) got it working as expected. I'm just seeking for some clarification around the 'auto updating' based on the 'queueVersion' value.

Our schedules which are feeding the programmed radio can change from time to time. These changes should be reflected on the Sonos Players as soon as possible. For what I understand this should be possible by modifying the `queueVersion` property in both `GET /context`, `GET /itemWindow` and `GET /version`.

Looking at the `GET /version` [documentation](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/cloud-queue-api/get-version/) I see that Players *"[...] are responsible for periodically polling this [QueueVersion] value to detect changes in the cloud queue track list, [...]"*.

I've monitored our API logs for about 15 minutes in which I would expect at least a `GET /version` request, but none showed up. The only calls I'm seeing are `POST /timePlayed`.

Can anyone (from the Sonos team perhaps?) clarify what this interval is set to, or how it can be controlled?

Comment: I've noticed a section in the [https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/](documentation) which mentions that the `/version` is at the end of every song, with a max of 10 minutes. 
Would this be dependent on a setting or something which we can control when returning the `/context` information?

Comment: Were you able to get this working? In all my attempts I'm also not receiving any calls to /version.

Comment: Not really actually. Still struggling to get it to work flawlessly. It seems to be working now and then, but some (I assume:) error or wrong response causes the player to stop polling, eventually causing playback to stop.

It would be great to know if there's any proper way on how to debug a player. Right now you're kinda sitting in the dark as soon as it stops playing. Maybe @yrg has some good insights on this?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you aren't seeing `GET /version` requests, there may be an error in your configuration.

The player sends a `GET /version` request every 5 minutes when paused and every 10 minutes when playing. This is by design, not depending on any setting that you can control. However, players fetch new tracks as needed using `GET /itemWindow`. The player requires a version in your response, so it doesn't send a  `GET /version` request in this case. After the player gets a new item window, it resets the polling interval to another 10 minutes.

See the [Play audio (cloud queue)](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/) page for details.